# Burn WMV to DVD on a Mac

Tags: macos, wmv

I have a WMV and I would like to make a video DVD. What is the cheapest way to get from WMV to DVD? I already have a burning program (Toast).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [VisualHub](http://www.versiontracker.com/dyn/moreinfo/macosx/30028) for simple drag-n-drop video file conversion.

Should be able to create DVDs from WMV for you - I did WMV to iTunes yesterday so I know it handles them as an input format and DVD is an output option (you can even choose to burn or not)

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll check it out. Shareware... hmmm....

Comment: Its discontinued so I wouldn't worry about donations. Fully functional and without nags as I recall....

Comment: Cool, thanks for that. I'll make you best answer since you could use the points :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Install [Flip4Mac's WMV Player](http://www.telestream.net/flip4mac-wmv/overview.htm) (free)
2. In Toast, choose the option for creating a DVD-Video disc
3. Drag the WMV to toast
4. Burn
5. Toast will take care of conversion and the rest

Comment: This is probably best answer, but I try to distribute the points around :)  Thanks again.

Comment: @Yar: I... killl... youuu!!~~ :) Seriously, don't worry about awarding points to best answer or what, most of us I believe are here to help people out - points are a bonus, good to have, but it won't kill us to not have it too. more importantly, SuperUser.com keeps our mind sharp and allow us to stay in touch with relevant problems happening in tech-land.

Answer (score 2):

You might also want to take a look at [VideoMonkey](http://videomonkey.org/) - it's another video transcoding app for the Mac similar to VisualHub which was already mentioned.  However, unlike VisualHub, VideoMonkey is still under active development.  (It's also free)  With it you can convert your WMV into a format that the Mac tools such as iTunes, iDVD, etc. can understand (like H.264 or MPEG4).